# Cheapest way to insert record in an ordered table in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database

My table has an order column like this one:

```
id | order
----------
1  | 100
3  | 200
2  | 300
```

The user can re-order the items
The user should be able to insert an item at an arbitrary order. e.g.

```
id | order
----------
1  | 100
4  | 150  * new item
3  | 200
2  | 300
```

How do I set up the order column to do this in the most efficient and "clean" way. Using the order between the predecessor and successor (150 in the example above) has the disadvantage that I have to re-order the table if the order values become too small.

Comment: Try to consider join table design. Example: http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/img/manymany-links.gif

Answer (score 0):

You can use [act as list gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/acts_as_list) to solve the sorting and reordering, check the [gem documentation](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list).

Comment: Thank you. It looks really promising. Do you know how SQL-efficient it is? Does it fire many queries when you are changing the position of an item?

Comment: I had used it in many apps and all of those have good performance